# Which climates do you expect there would be in this alternate tilted Earth? What climate would you be living in?

Tags: climate

[image]

OK, so the North Pole in this alternate Earth is -11.6, 166.9 in real life. BTW, what kinda climate do you think you would end up having? And here's a formula for find which latitude you're gonna be: Find the distance between where you are and -11.6, 166.9, divide the result by 111, then subtract the result from 90.

Comment: I'm honestly not at all sure that this is answerable according to our standards. It looks like you mostly just slapped the poles near the equator, while keeping other areas also near the equator climatically extremely different from the "poles" (which, frankly, makes no sense) and then ask us for an unbounded list of climates at different places of the resulting world. The former is just weird but might *possibly* be answerable, but the latter makes this either opinion-based or too broad, depending on which way you slice it. Either way, I feel this may be at high risk of being put on hold.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you take the site [Tour], as well as review our list of suggestions for [how to write a good question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3624/29).

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! In addition to what @MichaelKjörling said above, I find the image that you have in the question somewhat confusing - that looks like you've got a map with Antarctica at the centre and distorted everything around it to fit on a (2D) rectangle (which also causes the distortion to be different in different directions, making it a bit stranger to look at), which I for one find a bit confusing as it doesn't at all display that the world's been tilted, which is what you're talking about in your question

Comment: Are you asking what would be the effect of changing earths axial tilt on earths climate? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: TBH, I was inspired by this: http://www.worlddreambank.org/T/TURNOVIA.HTM

Comment: Please visit worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com and search for "high concept".

Comment: In addition to what has been said, if you are asking about a highly complex field, it might be helpful if you could state your education in physics/meteorology or whatever you have to offer or show your own research so far. One cannot answer that question, but one can answer it to a certain degree if one is an expert in that field - but you might simply not be able to understand the terminology if let's say you are a 16 year old kid with some (mild western) school education for example. Such information also shows how detailed an answer should be and where to start.

Comment: If the only variable for "climate" was the axial tilt of the planet, this would be an answerable question.  Unfortunately, the ratio of water to land, the salinity of the ocean, the nature of currents, the configuration of the land, where the high and low spots are, etc., etc. etc., all contribute to "climate."  You can reduce those variables by using the earth "if we run the axis through this line of the Earth, what would happen to our climate?" that might make this answerable.